# Resources for designing a social network?

Tags: social-networking

I'm working on designing an online art community that's not all that dissimilar from deviantART or other art communities.

I'm looking for resources (books, websites, blogs) that would guide me in some of the technical, social, and legal issues I'll need to address in designing the site.

I've started with [Here Comes Everybody](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1594201536) by Clay Shirky. I just need to know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

It won't address technical or legal issues at all, but [Here Comes Everybody](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1594201536) by Clay Shirkey is an interesting read behind the dynamics of social networks and how new technologies change the way people organize. I'd expect it to be a good source for inspiration.

Comment: Actually I already have read it. :) Should have mentioned it earlier. It was a very good starting place but some of the concepts need some translation for me. I don't completely get all of it.

Answer (score 2):

For technical stuff, here's what you need:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321/
[image: Programming Collective Intelligence]
<sub>(source: [oreilly.com](http://oreilly.com/catalog/covers/9780596529321_cat.gif))</sub>

For the social aspect, check out [Tribes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1591842336) by [Seth Godin](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/)

[Tribes http://classes.tametheweb.com/shelfless/files/2009/02/sethgodin-tribescover.jpg](http://classes.tametheweb.com/shelfless/files/2009/02/sethgodin-tribescover.jpg)

Comment: Collective Intelligence looks interesting. Thanks!